# SOAP Requests in Dojo

Tags: soap, dojo

I am trying to make a call to a SOAP web service through Dojo, but have found no relevant, up-to-date documentation on how to make a SOAP request.

Does anyone have any experience making a SOAP request in Dojo?

Answer (score 2):

IBM has something [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.wasfpweb20/wasfpweb20/6.0/Runtime/was_web20fp_Ajax-Client-Runtime/player.html). Unfortunately, [it's not supported in Dojo](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5387). However, [this library](http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/en/) could be of use for JavaScript to SOAP connectivity.