# How to consume webservice in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

please tell me how to consume webservice (.net) using javascript.

its SOAP.

Thanks

Comment: What type of web service? RESTful? SOAP? RPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use AJAX.

In particular the [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object.

Look at the [jQuery ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - it makes AJAX easier to use.

Comment: @Rajesh Rolen- DotNet Developer - There are samples in the links. Your question is so generic, that the only read answer to it can only be as generic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Javascript library that consumes SOAP out of the box. [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) offers a lot of functionality in that direction, RPC-calls for example,  and is probably the one that comes closest. 
IBM did some work there that you might want to check out.

This (including Dojo) is a lot of non-trivial stuff to learn but SOAP is a nasty beast, if you really need to interface to a SOAP service with JS you will have to invest some time.

See:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-dojowebresponse/index.html?ca=drs-

[SOAP Requests in Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495073/soap-requests-in-dojo)

Answer (score 0):

Both .asmx and .svc (wcf) expose javascript enabled bindings - this is easy to find on the internet.

Example:

- http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html

Normally you just append /js to the url of the endpoint and javascript providing a proxy is returned.

This proxy code relies on the ASP.NET AJAX framework, but you can easily use it with any other ajax-enabling framework by using [this shim](http://kinsey.no/blog/index.php/2009/10/28/using-wcfsvcs-automatically-generated-javascript-proxies-_without_-asp-net-ajax/).